# A simple complex equality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve in complex numbers
$$cos(z)=isin(z)$$

I use the definition of complex trignomentric function, then use substitution $\omega=e^{iz}$ and try to solve the quadratic equation, but I was stopped when it came to the results, because I got $\omega_{1}=e^{iz_{1}}=\frac{-2\sqrt{2}i}{1-i}$ and $\omega_{2}=e^{iz_{2}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}i}{1-i}$ and I don't know how to move on.

Comment: $$\cos z = i \sin z \implies \cos z - i \sin z = 0 \implies e^{-iz} = 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read

$$\cos z-i\sin z=e^{-iz}=0$$ which has no solution.